# Insert Unicode symbol in Geany at cursor position

Tags: geany

I want to insert certain Unicode symbol at current cursor position when Control-L is pressed. How to achieve this in Geany? (symbol ロ for example)

Answer (score 1):

Had a similar desire.  Here is a solution that makes use of the [GeanyPy plugin](http://codebrainz.github.io/geanypy/):

1. Install and enable GeanyPy plugin that allows you to write Python plugins for Geany (this is available as geany-plugin-py in Ubuntu 16.04).
2. Place the following in your plugin directory (for me this was `~/.config/geany/plugins/`):

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import gtk
import geany


class InsertSymbols(geany.Plugin):

    __plugin_name__ = "InsertSymbols"
    __plugin_version__ = "0.1"
    __plugin_description__ = "Insert symbols e.g. unicode"
    __plugin_author__ = "klimaat"

    chars = ['°', '×', '²', '³', '±', 'µ', '·', 'ロ']

    def __init__(self):

        self.symbol_menuitem = gtk.MenuItem("Insert Symbol")
        self.symbol_menuitem.show()

        symbol_submenu = gtk.Menu()
        self.symbol_menuitem.set_submenu(symbol_submenu)

        for char in self.chars:
            char_item = gtk.MenuItem(char)
            char_item.show()
            char_item.connect("activate", self.on_insert_symbol_clicked)
            symbol_submenu.append(char_item)

        geany.main_widgets.tools_menu.append(self.symbol_menuitem)

    def cleanup(self):
        self.symbol_menuitem.destroy()

    def on_insert_symbol_clicked(self, data):
        char = data.get_label()
        doc = geany.document.get_current()
        if doc:
            pos = doc.editor.scintilla.get_current_position()
            doc.editor.scintilla.insert_text(char)
            doc.editor.scintilla.set_current_position(pos+2)
```

You *should* now have a "Insert Symbol" item under "Tools".

Probably much better ways to do it...

Answer (score 0):

Macros Plugin helped. It allows to assign a Control-L key, and it has a command to insert any text at cursor. Took some time to figure, but not difficult.